# no API available to extract or create a archive with password in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, dotnetzip

Unfortunately in Windows store 8.1 there is no API available to extract  or create a archive with password ,at least this what i find out after a lot of recherche on the web,

And because this is very important for us to find out something, we created a package on nuget.org that works like magic. Basically we manage to create/extract archive with password but sadly this does not pass the certification Kit evaluation.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZipforWindows8.1/

I wonder if anyone can help us to get this API pass the test.

this is what i get in the certification Kit evaluation

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/465599

Comment: From the certification kit information, it seems like the NuGet package uses a .NET Framework library to target Windows 8/Store? If it is indeed a .NET class library you will not be able to included it in your Windows 8(.1)/Store app. But do take a look at [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zlib.Portable/) NuGet package instead; maybeit provides you with the functionality you need.